# Issues launching ROS on startup

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-groovy, startup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS: groovy
OS: ubuntu 12.04

What we are trying to do is have roscore start upon boot (have this working now) and then execute a launch file.
I am not a linux person, so I feel I am really not approaching this the right way. Currently, this is what I have attempted:

1. roscore is launched via a script in /etc/init.d. This is fine.
2. I want to launch my launch file on boot. Manually, I do it like this: roslaunch rover.launch. It works great.
3. I would like this to start on boot, so I tried the following:
   inside new script (boot.sh) - note i disabled password prompt for sudo:

   sudo su - roboops
   /home/roboops/groovycat/scripts/bootRoverLaunch.sh

   bootRoverLaunch.sh:

   cd /home/roboops/groovycat/
   source devel/setup.sh
   sleep 5
   roslaunch rover.launch > /home/roboops/groovycat/scripts/startup.log
4. I went to "startup applications" and added "bash /home/roboops/groovycat/scripts/boot.sh"
5. Tried rebooting. Roscore starts, and the launch files executes. However, the nodes malfunction and don't work correctly (They work fine when started using the launch file directly in a terminal window. Oddly, it also works fine if I log out and back in once)

More specifically, here is the problem when using the above script to launch:

I am trying to run two nodes:

-joystick node (publishes joy topic)
-motor control node (listens to joy topic and outputs commands to motor controllers via serial)

Joystick node starts successfully and If I do rostopic echo joy, I can see the values.
Motor control node is listed as running but if I run roswtf it says:

```
Found 3 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /Drivetrain

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /Drivetrain->/rosout (/rosout)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/Drivetrain/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/Drivetrain/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://Rover:58631]
 * service [/Drivetrain/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/Drivetrain/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://Rover:58631]
```

The idea is, I need everything to automatically start on power-up. There will be no input devices/monitor connected to it when it is in use.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140426/issues-launching-ros-on-startup/) by [rb](https://answers.ros.org/users/13396/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2014-03-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We recommend using the [robot_upstart](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart) package we developed. It's simple, seems to do everything you need, and has already been deployed on dozens of robots.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-05-29**:
I notice the package only has a hydro/devel branch. Does this work for groovy?

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-07-07**:
Hi Andrew, yes, robot_upstart should work with groovy as well as hydro, as long as you don't mind doing a source install of it in your workspace.

**Comment by [julien](https://answers.ros.org/users/21518/julien/) on 2015-02-02**:
Hi Mike,

I'm also trying to use robot_upstart since 3hours without results.... is it possible to use this package with indigo???

Tks

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2015-02-05**:
@julien: I'm not Mike, but I know we use it to run our [Jackal](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Jackal), which is Indigo-only. Have you tried using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-robot-upstart
```

to install it? Instructions to use it are on both the ROS wiki and its github page.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-08-14**:
Note, this package is no longer supported on Kinetic.

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2017-04-09**:
Support for Kinetic has been added

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I start my roslaunch on start up using cron (http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron) and screen (http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/screen).

I have a /home/user/autostart/autostart_screens.sh that get executed by cron @reboot (Meaning whenever the PC is booted). You can set these startup files via `crontab` command. See `crontab --help`. My current `crontab -l` gives:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot bash /home/user/autostart/autostart_screens.sh
```

My autostart_screens.sh starts and detaches two screen sessions and logs any thing happening inbetween to a log file. It looks like:

```
# !/bin/bash
LOG_FILE=/home/user/autostart/logs/log_autostart_screens.txt

echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "#############################################" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "Running autostart_screens.sh" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo $(date) >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "#############################################" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "Logs:" >> ${LOG_FILE}

set -e
set -v

{

screen -d -m bash /home/user/autostart/start_roscore.sh
screen -d -m bash /home/user/autostart/start_roslaunch.sh

} &>> ${LOG_FILE}
```

Note that it is not blocking as it just starts the screens.

The start_roscore.sh looks like:

```
# !/bin/bash
LOG_FILE=/home/user/autostart/logs/log_start_roscore.txt
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "#############################################" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "Running start_roscore.sh" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo $(date) >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "#############################################" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "Logs:" >> ${LOG_FILE}

set -e

{

source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source /home/user/workspace/ros_hydro/catkin/devel/setup.bash

export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/user/workspace/ros_hydro/catkin

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311/ ##e. g. Master
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.15                   ##e. g. Own IP

sleep 5

} &>> ${LOG_FILE}

set -v

{

roscore

} &>> ${LOG_FILE}
```

The start_roslaunch.sh looks like:

```
# !/bin/bash
LOG_FILE=/home/user/autostart/logs/log_start_roslaunch.txt
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "#############################################" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "Running start_roslaunch.sh" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo $(date) >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "#############################################" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}
echo "Logs:" >> ${LOG_FILE}

set -e

{
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source /home/user/workspace/ros_hydro/catkin/devel/setup.bash

export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/user/workspace/ros_hydro/catkin

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311/
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.15

sleep 8

} &>> ${LOG_FILE}

set -v

{

roslaunch my_pkg my_launch.launch

} &>> ${LOG_FILE}
```

All logs go to /home/user/autostart/logs. After start youn can verify your ros being up using `rosnode list`. You can monitor your screens using `screen -ls`. Note that the timeout in start_roslaunch.sh is longer than in start_roscore.sh. In order for shutting down the nodes on my computer if I want to use it for something else I use this script:

```
# !/bin/bash

for session in $(screen -ls | grep -o '[0-9]\{5\}')
do
    screen -S "${session}" -X quit;
done
```

It sends a Crlt+C to all running screen sessions.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-08-14**:
Why are you running both roscore and roslaunch in separate scripts? roslaunch will automatically run roscore if needed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I start my roscore on boot simply by adding this line in "/etc/rc.local" before "exit0":

```
su pi -c "source /home/pi/YOURWS/devel/setup.sh ; roscore  > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

the "> /dev/null" means its logs dont get stored anywhere and "&" at the end means it starts in the background. You cant start roscore in root mode, that's why "su pi -c" is at the start of the command. Replace "/home/pi/YOURWS" with your workspace name and destination.

---

Originally posted by [CimeROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/23627/cimeros/) with karma: 41 on 2017-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2018-05-24**:
Works, and it's simple !  I have spent hours trying to use robot_upstart, but it needs too  many files and devices to have their permissions changed. I used a launch file:
su ubuntu -c "source /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh ; roslaunch biped biped_robot.launch  > /dev/null 2>&1 &"